# Are heap allocated member references a terrible idea? Why?

Tags: c++, memory, reference, heap-memory

To best explain this problem, I have constructed a simple example.  Say I have a class `Blob` as follows:

```
class Blob
{
    string personalName;
    string& familyName;
}
```

A `Blob` can be spawned by the Creator (aka Programmer), at which point it gets to pick a `personalName` and, since it has the privilege of being a 1st generation `Blob`, it gets to pick it's own `familyName`.

Alternatively, a `Blob` can be created by spawning off an existing `Blob`, at which point it picks its own `personalName`, but shares a `familyName` with all other `Blob`s that have been cloned in this family.  If one `Blob` changes the family name, all other family members get that name change automatically.

So far, this sounds all well and good, until when writing the `Blob` constructor I see this:

```
Blob::Blob() :
    personalName(pickName()),
    familyName(pickFamilyName())
{ }

...

string& Blob::pickFamilyName()
{
    return *(new string("George"));
}   // All Blobs have family name "George" in this example
```

Eek!  Allocating memory on the heap then assigning it to a reference variable?!  That looks scary!

Are my instincts correct that there is something very wrong with this, or does it only feel strange to me because it is not a common pattern?  If there is something wrong, what is it?  Why is this a bad design?

Note: It would be important to free that heap-allocated memory by reference counting and deleting the memory when the last Blob is destructed, or by some other method.

Comment: Binding references to dereferenced pointers pointing at dynamically allocated objects is definitely a code smell.

Comment: `Blob::pickFamilyName` returns an `int&`?

Comment: @ildjarn thanks, I've fixed the text of the question

Comment: Why not `string Blob::pickFamilyName() {return std::string("George");}`?

Comment: Anything stopping you using `shared_ptr<string>`? Seems to meet all the requirements.

Comment: @Toolbox: there is nothing undefined about that; he's not returning a reference anymore.

Comment: Reference data members are yucky because they effectively prevent assignment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only time it makes sense to store a reference as a class member is when:

1. The data is not owned by the class and the class is not responsible for freeing it;
2. The lifetime of the referred object is guaranteed to be longer than the lifetime of the containing object.

Your example violates rule 1.

Comment: But what is the reasoning behind your rule 1?  It seems like mine is a good example showing a situation where a class would want to own the data _and_ keep it as a reference.  Your answer is "It's a bad idea because it breaks this rule I have."  I still don't understand _why_ it is a bad idea.

Comment: @Cory, because a reference *by definition* refers to an object that exists in some other context. Your reference is to an anonymous hunk of heap, whose context went away when the pointer was destroyed at the end of `pickFamilyName`. A much better choice would be a smart pointer.

Answer (score 8):

I think the "smelly" part of it is storing the variable as a reference to a string, since it can become difficult to keep track of whether it's a valid object. Why not use something like:

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::string> Blob::pickFamilyName()
{
    return boost::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string("George"));
}
```

**EDIT**

As per Praetorian's suggestion, you can avoid manually allocating memory yourself altogether:

```
boost::shared_ptr<std::string> Blob::pickFamilyName()
{
    return boost::make_shared<std::string>("George");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, include boost and it brings with it a few thousand header files to parse... then watch your compile times skyrocket.

Comment: Or even better `return boost::make_shared<std::string>("George");`

Comment: C Johnson:  most programmers know not to `#include` **every** boost header in every source file.  Most boost headers are well-contained.  And `shared_ptr` is in `tr1` **and** C++-11, so if you have it in your implementation you don't need boost.

Comment: @CJohnson: Surely you aren't arguing that compile times trump *basic* resource management? A working program is more important than a quick-compiling program.

Comment: or use std::shared_ptr now :)

Comment: @C Johnson: which version of boost includes thousands of header files from `boost/shared_ptr.hpp`? Mine includes about 30, and my human brain isn't capable of watching the milliseconds that that adds to the compile time.

Answer (score 1):

One argument would be consistency: `operator new` returns a pointer and `operator delete` takes a pointer, so it is expected that the type used for referencing dynamically allocated objects would also be pointer, not reference. This is a serious argument: if you are being inconsistent and going against programmer habits for no good reason, you are confusing them and breeding bugs. Nobody would normally expect a function that returns a reference to create new objects on the heap that the calling code then has to delete, so sooner or later somebody will forget to do it.

But there are pragmatic reasons also that pointers can be reassigned and that they can be set to null makes them more convenient for handling dynamically allocated objects. In your example, Blob class is responsible for calling delete on the reference member. You would normally do that in the destructor. But imagine you want to free the memory sooner: with pointers you can assign assign null to them after you call delete, and then let their destructor safely call delete again, with reference members you are left with a dangling reference that you can't do anything about.

Even more serious issue is exception safety: if Blob had a longer initializer list or a non-empty body, it would be possible for the constructor to throw after the call to pickFamilyName(). In that case the destructor doesn't get called and you have a memory leak. Ideally, you would use RAII for this, but with pointers it's also possible to assign the pointer to null in the initializer list, and then point it to the newly created object in the constructor body in a try/catch block that would ensure the object is deleted even if the constructor throws and there is no destructor call. This again can't be done with references.